# While making build Cause: error=13, Permission denied

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo

Hi am working on expo project while I try to run my project, am facing issue.

`> Task :app:exponentPrebuildStep FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:exponentPrebuildStep'.

> A problem occurred starting process 'command './node_modules/expokit/detach-scripts/run-exp.sh''
> `

Cause: error=13, Permission denied

I don't know how to fix it, tried clean, invalidate caches, rebuild but everything is working fine but when I give `expo start -c`  and run my project then am facing this error and I tried `expo publish` rerun my app but I don't know why this error is coming MacBook.

Comment: did you find solution? After expo publish when i create android/ios build getting error - Process 'command './node_modules/expokit/detach-scripts/run-exp.sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: No, But I moved to bare flow Because the expo team will not support expokit.

Comment: @RaviBhandari I'm also having this error. Did you have any luck finding solution? I'm still stuck. We're not in position to migrate to bare workflow so we to find solution for this.